# Does the core Moneris payment processor work?

Tags: payment-processor, evaluating-civicrm, moneris

I have a US-based org that is exploring using Moneris with a CiviCRM contribution page. The core Moneris payment processor seems a little rough -- is anyone using it/does it work? The [Wiki page for Moneris configuration](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Moneris+Configuration+Guide) mentions changes to the mpgClasses.php file but the link to the patch is non-existent. Are the required changes documented anywhere else?

I also notice there is a newer "[replacement version](https://github.com/adixon/ca.civicrm.moneris)" of the core files in process (by [Alan Dixon](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/users/233/alan-dixon)), but apparently [recurring is still "fragile" and it is not working for the US](https://github.com/adixon/ca.civicrm.moneris/issues/1#issuecomment-88291427) (yet). Will this version end up in core?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Our general strategy with payment processors is to get most of them out of core and into extensions, where they can be better maintained, so no, this is not going back into core. In fact, it's because Moneris didn't ever respond to the license questions about their mpgClasses.php file that it started falling out of core ...

I'd be happy to work with you to get the US code working. Contact me via the form:

http://blackflysolutions.ca/contact

with details about your needs and I can update my extension to support US$.

Alternatively - if your organization is a non-profit, I'd also recommend you compare iATS Payments services, they tend to be better (less expensive, more features, better service).

Comment: Thanks Alan. I will be in touch via your form to see what needs to happen, and will probably inquire as to whether Moneris is negotiable.

Answer (score 1):

There is a discussion within the group about payment processors and the future. We are encouraging any new development to happen outside of core and in an extension. I suspect there might be some changes coming to the payment processor architecture from work being done at the colorado sprint (happening right now).

I dont think there has been any change with moneris recently. I've asked alan dixon to update the status of the code base here.