# how do I set up the Moneris mpgClasses.php file to work with my wordpress install

Tags: wordpress, payment-processor, moneris

http://java-prod.civicrm.osuosl.org:8090/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=124813669

This is what I've been using, I have the php file placed in the packages/services folder, but Moneris is not showing up as an option for Payment Processors still.

rchapman

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it myself, but a quick search pulled up [this extension](https://github.com/adixon/ca.civicrm.moneris) by Alan Dixon and this related post: [Does the core Moneris payment processor work?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/764/does-the-core-moneris-payment-processor-work)

Also, have you looked at the documentation?

- [Setting up Moneris Hosted Payment Processor for CiviCRM](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Setting+up+Moneris+Hosted+Payment+Processor+for+CiviCRM)
- [Moneris Configuration Guide](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Moneris+Configuration+Guide)

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, that's moving towards my goal. But it still doesn't answer too many questions about how to enable things on Wordpress install. The instructions are quite vague and aren't helpful on where to download the extension or where that folder is. :(

Comment: I got further, trying to install Alan Dixon's extension, but when I tried to install it from the list of extensions, I got the following:

 Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.
DB Error: constraint violation
Return to home page.

I have not been a fan of chasing civi errors before. Is there truly no other option for moneris payments on wordpress installs?

~ross

Comment: @Ross - That's an incomplete error.  If you post a separate question with the full results of the error, someone can potentially help you.  To get full error messages, In CiviCRM, please go to **Administer menu > System Settings > Debugging and Error Handling**, select "Yes" to both "Enable Debugging" and "Display Backtrace", and press "Save".  Repeat the problem that caused your error, and you'll see much a much more detailed error.

Comment: @jon-g great, I'll do that, thanks!